# Laravel Multiple Count in 1 Query and display it on my views using @foreach?

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

Sorry im new to this framework, Im planning to improve my code it is hassle to declare tons of variable just to get the count of the values. help me guys see my code.

```
$broken = LiipRepairMaintenanceItem::join('liip_psrm_components', 'liip_psrm_components.psrm_components_id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.id')
    ->where('liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id', '=', $psrm_maintenance->id)
    ->whereIn('liip_psrm_components.problem_code',  [1])
    ->count();

    $broken_negligence = LiipRepairMaintenanceItem::join('liip_psrm_components', 'liip_psrm_components.psrm_components_id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.id')
    ->where('liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id', '=', $psrm_maintenance->id)
    ->whereIn('liip_psrm_components.problem_code',  [2])
    ->count();

    $drop = LiipRepairMaintenanceItem::join('liip_psrm_components', 'liip_psrm_components.psrm_components_id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.id')
    ->where('liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id', '=', $psrm_maintenance->id)
    ->whereIn('liip_psrm_components.problem_code',  [3])
    ->count();

    $sliced_by_Forklift = LiipRepairMaintenanceItem::join('liip_psrm_components', 'liip_psrm_components.psrm_components_id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.id')
    ->where('liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id', '=', $psrm_maintenance->id)
    ->whereIn('liip_psrm_components.problem_code',  [4])
    ->count();


switch ($status) {
        case 'getApprove':
            // Title
            $title = Lang::get('liipPsrmMaintenance::repairMaintenance/title.repair_maintenance_approve');
            //Show the page
            return View::make('liipPsrmMaintenance::view.approve', compact('broken', 'broken_negligence', 'drop', 'sliced_by_Forklift '));
            break;
```

}

views

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                    <form role="form">


                        <!-- Broken/Cracked -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>B -Broken/Cracked</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static">{{{ $broken }}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ./ Broken/Cracked -->

                        <!-- Broken/Cracked -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>B -Broken/Cracked due to negligence</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static">{{{ $broken_negligence }}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ./ Broken/Cracked -->

                        <!-- Dry rot -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>DR -Dry rot</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static">{{{ $sliced_by_Forklift }}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ./ Dry rot -->

                        <!-- dropped -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>D -dropped</label>
                            <p class="form-control-static">{{{ $drop }}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <!-- ./ dropped -->

                    </form>
                </div>
```

is it possible to compress it in 1 query for more proccessing speed then i will call it on my views using @foreach($broken->broken_negligence as $broken). im suffering from slow code proccessing because of this, help me guys. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may use a single query with conditional aggregation:

```
$result = LiipRepairMaintenanceItem::join('liip_psrm_components', 'liip_psrm_components.psrm_components_id', '=', 'liip_psrm_items.id')
    ->select(DB::raw("COUNT(CASE WHEN liip_psrm_components.problem_code IN (".[1]." THEN 1 END) AS broken" .
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN liip_psrm_components.problem_code IN (".[2]." THEN 1 END) AS broken_negligence" .
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN liip_psrm_components.problem_code IN (".[3]." THEN 1 END) AS drop" .
        "COUNT(CASE WHEN liip_psrm_components.problem_code IN (".[4]." THEN 1 END) AS sliced_by_Forklift"))
    ->where('liip_psrm_items.psrm_items_id', '=', $psrm_maintenance->id);
```

Note that the above code might be vulnerable to SQL injection, if the arrays (`[1]`, `[2]`, etc.) are not sterilized.

This answer corresponds to the following raw MySQL query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.problem_code IN [1] THEN 1 END) AS broken,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.problem_code IN [2] THEN 1 END) AS broken_negligence,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.problem_code IN [3] THEN 1 END) AS drop,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.problem_code IN [4] THEN 1 END) AS sliced_by_Forklift
FROM liip_psrm_items t1
INNER JOIN liip_psrm_components t2
    ON t1.id = t2.psrm_components_id
WHERE
    t1.psrm_items_id = <some value>;
```

Comment: thank you for the response sir, then how may i call this 1 by one? on foreach statement

Comment: One by one?  I thought you were asking for a single query?

Comment: i will display it on my views, im new to this framework. is it posible to call thath eliases on my views?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to do here.  Maybe edit your question and state the actual problem.